# Mathematica cannot find the solution of this ODE

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to find the exact solution of this ODE:

$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac {  a_1B^2(x) - \frac{a_2}{y^{10/3}} - \frac{a_3}{y^2}+ \frac{a_4}{y^2B(x)} }
       {B^2(x) - \frac{a_5}{y^3}},
$$
with

$ B(x) = a_6+a_7e^{-x/a_8} $

$y$, $x$, and the constant coefficients $a_i$ (and therefore $B(x)$) are all real and strictly positive. Mathematica cannot find a solution for this ODE. I am trying to find a substitution that allows me to get a separable ODE. Or I am aiming to get a  [Bernoulli ODE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation), which can be then transformed into a separable ODE. I tried a few substitutions such as:

$u=B^2(x) - \frac{a_5}{y^3}$

and

$u=\frac{a_5}{y^3}$

but with no solution found by Mathematica. Do you think this ODE has not an exact solution (I am only interested in exact solutions, I know how to solve it numerically)

Comment: Please also post some codes you have tried for this problem.

Comment: `Maple 2020.1` also can't find analytical solution.Many ODEs do not have symbolic solutions in terms of commonly defined functions. The ODE in the question probably falls in that category.